# How to call one servlet project to another JPA project

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jpa-2.0

I have two projects in my eclipse 
1.Servlet project 
2.JPA project

when i am calling from servlet to another JPA projets class.
class not found error is throwing.

only first projects war file is configured in tomcat 7.

Comment: I think you need to include the missing classes in project1 from project2.

Comment: already did but not working.

Comment: How are you adding project 2 into 1, can you try exporting jar & include it in lib folder of web project, then deply war in tomcat.